# Are there any stats on how the new "Ask a Question" performed during testing?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, statistics, user-experience, ask-question-form

I like the [new "Ask a Question" interface](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/?cb=1). I particularly like the warning pop-up very new users get **before** they get to start writing:

> [image: asking a good question popup]

And the "expectations regulator" they get afterwards:

> [image: post question popup]

As far as I can see, this seems to be deployed across the board, so I assume the A/B testing phase has already ended. Do we have any stats about how this new design impacted question quality/reception?

If numbers are still being gathered, can we expect the results of how this performed (re: question closure, question score, even other possibilities as edits performed after on the question, etc) to be published as well?

Comment: And now I see [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/?cb=1). I guess the question is moot. Or maybe I can leave it up until enough data has been acquired?

Comment: It's still early. I doubt they have the data ready - getting it takes time.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. When I saw the new editor I assumed I had missed the A/B test, and maybe this had been running for a while without me knowing. But that doesn't seem to be the case. I think I'll leave the question up anyway. Some positive feedback is not a bad thing to have, and would **really** like to see if this performs well and has a positive impact in question queality.

Comment: I'm honestly concerned what 2 modal windows hope to accomplish. The general issue with users is that they don't read information and just hit accept; so now we'll likely have exactly the same problem we had before, AND 2 new modal windows.

Comment: Side note: "answer clarifying question" is... strange? So we are basically confuse users of what "answers" and "comments" are on the site from get go... and then look all surprised when people can't distinguish between "comment", "question" and "answer"...

Comment: The A/B test is still ongoing and more changes are upcoming that will also be A/B tested but I appreciate the thoughts and feedback even so! We'll review this (and anything tagged `ask-question-form`) alongside data as we make plans to iterate. Thanks!

Comment: Relevant: [The new ask page is now live on the network!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344513/the-new-ask-page-is-now-live-on-the-network)