# Has there been any analysis of the effect of the change to "reward askers"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, asking-questions, statistics

Last year, there was [a change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/391250/upvotes-on-questions-will-now-be-worth-the-same-as-upvotes-on-answers) to the reputation-award algorithm to ensure questions were rewarded with more points.

Has there been any retrospective analysis conducted on this change, to see if it delivered the intended outcomes?

Comment: Isn't it too early to say? I don't think the activity is uniform over the year, so maybe we can't really compare the data accurately yet.

Comment: Shog, Julia, and Megan are no longer with the company. It seems like many of the people who would have been involved in the analysis for this change are no longer here. There is a brand new "Chief Product Officer". The current Director for Public Q&A does not seem to be very interested in sharing back this kind of information. I think it's overly optimistic to expect an answer regarding this. Some time ago I also asked a similar question regarding the new "Ask" interface. (Spoiler alert: [I didn't get any meaningful response either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389850/))

Comment: to me, it had a very positive effect of masking [truly useful 3CV change](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/391832/839601) and preemptively shutting down all possible complaints that would inevitably follow without it. Whoever now would start whining that 3CV is hostile to askers will be immediately countered by "how dare you say that now that such a great effort was demonstrated in doubling rep points given to askers!"